# How do I acquire the value of a ASP label if it is nested? (client-side)

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

So there is a ASP checkboxlist that gets rendered to the table and in the code behind the checkboxes get bound with a label from a code table.  I need to display a text box only if a certain checkbox is checked off.

```
<table id="chkSomeCheckbox">
    <tbody>
       <tr>
     <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="chkSomeCheckbox_0">
          <label for="chkSomeCheckbox_0">Acme</label>
         </td>
         <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="chkSomeCheckbox_1">
          <label for="chkSomeCheckbox_1">Other</label>
         </td>
       </tr>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

The checkboxlist renders a table which the  element retains the ID.  I have tried to just get the value of the label when a checkbox is checked and then go from there to create my logic - but I can't seem to be able to grab the value of the label.  I have tried the following different ways:

```
$("#<%chkSomeCheckbox.ClientID> input").next("label").val();
```

or

```
$("#<%chkSomeCheckbox.ClientID> input").next().val();
```

I am using the input selector because when I get this first part working, I will need to do some logic on it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: First, this should be tagged as jQuery, as it is clearly about jQuery selectors. Second, is the HTML posted above the output of the ASP.NET server controls?

Comment: I didn't realize it wasn't in the JQuery section.  Secondly, yes this is the output by the ASP.NET server controls.

Answer (score 2):

This is tagged as ASP.NET rather than ASP so I'm curious as to why you are not using ASP.NET controls.  Also you have an extra `</tr>` tag in there.

You could do this:

```
<table id="chkSomeCheckbox">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSomeCheckbox_0" runat="server" 
             Text="Acme" Checked="true" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSomeCheckbox_1" runat="server" 
             Text="Other" Checked="false" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the `Page_Load` event of the code behind you could then check the `Checked` property of the `CheckBox` and then decide to display the area that you held the `Textbox` in or just change the `Visible` property of the `TextBox` itself.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (chkSomeCheckbox_0.Checked)
        {
            txtSomeTextbox.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried this?

```
$("#<%= chkSomeCheckbox.ClientID %> input").next("label").val();
```

In your code sample the ASP.NET inline statement is not closed (and also the "=" sign is missing).

Note: This will only work in the aspx/ascx file, not in a external JavaScript file.

Comment: Actually, I have found that the reason val() is not working is it does not work on labels, spans and other related HTML elements only with checkbox, list and similar inputs.  I have to use the HTML() method to acquire the value of the label.

Comment: However, even after doing so, it will only ever grab the first "label" element in the first <tr>.

Answer (score 0):

If you can grab a handle on the label that you want, you can probably call the .text() method to get the text of the label.  As such, I don't think that labels have a "value"

For example, if you wanted to append a textbox after the label based on which one was checked you could do this:

```
$("#chkSomeCheckbox > input").change(function(){
    $label = $(this).next();
    if($(this).attr("selected") == true)
    {
        //get label text
        foo = $label.text();

        //append textbox after the label, etc
        $label.append(textbox);
    }

});A
```